# How to sort by month, year in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have column of month and year that data type is `varbinary`.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM traffic
WHERE '2015'<= year AND year <='2015'
    AND NOT (
       ( 2015= year AND month <05) OR
        ( 2015= year AND month >11)
    ) ORDER BY Year, month;
```

The output is:

```
month
10
11
5
6
7
8
9
```

but I want

```
month
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

What can I do to get the expected output?

Comment: Column data types? (Don't store date/time values in varchar, use proper data types.)

Comment: month+0 will suffice, but perhaps store integers as integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
select * from traffic
WHERE '2015'<= year AND year <='2015'
    AND NOT (
       ( 2015= year AND month <05) OR
        ( 2015= year AND month >11)
    ) ORDER BY Year * 1,month * 1;
```

*1 will convert string data type into month integer.

Comment: Welcome ! If my answer solves your problem, you can accept my answer.

Comment: @khush I've been looking at your profile, and you never accept answers. Please take the time to mark the (V) at the left of the correct answer, so the people that answered you will get their reward .

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast the month string into int

```
order by cast(month as unsigned)
```

Comment: Also, add ASC so it go from smallest to biggest:

 order by cast(month as unsigned) ASC

Comment: @OriNachum `ASC` is the default ordering, no need to write it down.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to change the datatype of `year` and `month` to `INT` in table itself because it doesn't have any benefit when it's stored in `VARCHAR`, then run your own code and it will return expected result without making change

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> MODIFY <columnname> INT UNSIGNED;
```